# Programmable Unijunction transistors

Tags: transistors

I am currently learning electronic on my own. And I have a question about the circuit below.

Given: 2N6027 is a programmable unijunction transistors. (I'm not sure if that is the right schematic for it)

Question: The objective here is to make the LED oscillates on and off. I have tried all of the three circuits below, but only Circuit 1 works. Why circuit 2 does not work? I believe the resistors R2 and R3 in circuit 1 are connected in series anyway right?

Why does the PUT's gate have to be in between R2 and R3?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCGuAR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Below are the pictures of the Circuit 1

http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596153755-files/mkel_02/mkel_02_098.pdf
http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596153755-files/mkel_02/mkel_02_103.pdf

Comment: The 2N6027 has three leads.  Your schematics make it look like it has four.   Indeed, your symbol isn't right.  The favored symbol these days for a unijunction is an encircled diode with a third line entering the anode at an angle, such as shown about halfway down the page http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_7/8.html  This article starts off with another symbol, like  a JFET with the gate at an angle, for the non-programmable UJT.  Good article overall, by the way - go read it and then refine your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refer to my previous answers on this exercise:

[Make electronics - charles pratt - experiment 11](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79655/make-electronics-charles-pratt-experiment-11/79661#79661)

[PUT Base Resistors Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79815/put-base-resistors-question/79866#79866)

The resistors aren't exactly in series; they're constructing a *voltage divider*, putting the PUT's base voltage at $$ 27/(15+27) * 6V $$
This is the programmable part of a PUT which sets the on voltage for it. In circuits 2 and 3 the gate is connected to the negative rail and is therefore at 0V, preventing it from ever turning on.

As in my other answers, PUTs are an unusual near-obsolete part and I wouldn't bother learning about them.